# .h y .cpp con array de estructuras

Tags: c++, array, struct, bison

Buenas, necesito crear un header con un array de estructuras y un .cpp donde se implemente los metodos, y tiene que tener un struct, y crear un array de ese struct, para despues desde otro archivo crear ese array y hacer las operaciones con el mismo, es una especie de tabla q contiene un nombre un tipo y un valor
en el .h tengo:

```
#ifndef TABLA_H
#define TABLA_H


union dato
{
    int entero;     
    float real;
    int booleano; 

};

typedef struct mitabla {
     std::string Nombre;
     int Tipo;
     dato Valor;
};

mitabla tablasimb[10];


extern void nuevavarentera(int cont,std::string nombre,int tipo,int valor);


#endif
```

en tabla cpp de momento un solo metodo para probar:

```
#include "tabla.h"

void tabla :: nuevavarentera(int cont,std::string nombre,int tipo,int valor){

    std::transform(nombre.begin(), nombre.end(), nombre.begin(), ::toupper);

    tablasimb[cont].Nombre=nombre;

    tablasimb[cont].Tipo=tipo;

    tablasimb[cont].Valor.entero=valor;}
```

y en el archivo principal en el main quiero crearlo pero no puedo:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){


    tabla mitabla;
    mitabla.nuevavarentera(0,"mivariable",0,2);


}
```

Alguna idea de como crear este array de estructuras en el header y crearlo desde el main en otro archivo (hago los includes "tabla.h")

Comment: ¿El lenguaje es [tag:c] o [tag:c++]?

Comment: Machiomen no uses snippet de codigo porque [tag:c] y [tag:c++] no se pueden ejecutar. Los snippets son para HTML, JS y CSS

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Es C++ con estilo C ...

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver esta pregunta con [tag:bison]?

Comment: @NaCl si es C++ entonces no es C.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro lo se. Pero si es un lenguaje, no es otro. Las etiquetas [tag:c] y [tag:c++] rara vez tienen sentido juntas.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Por eso he dicho que es C++, no C XD

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta es muy general, y ademas tienes errores conceptuales, por eso tratare de solucionarte tus dudas y ademas de aclararte algunos conceptos.

> necesito crear un header con un array de estructuras y un .cpp donde se implemente los metodos, y tiene que tener un struct, y crear un array de ese struct, para despues desde otro archivo crear ese array

En el `.h` quieres definir los TIPOS de variables. Esto es correcto, es la idea general de tener un header file.

El error conceptual que tienes aqui, es que un array de elementos de un tipo, no es un tipo nuevo, es una declaracion de multiples instancias de un tipo. Por eso no debes declararlo en el `.h`.

Lo que si puedes hacer, es declarar un `struct` dentro del `.h`, que contenga un arreglo que desees. Dicho arreglo se instanciara, solo si se instancia la estructura que lo contiene.

Tu codigo quedaria algo asi:

En `tabla.h`

```
#ifndef TABLA_H
#define TABLA_H


union dato
{
    int entero;     
    float real;
    int booleano; 

};

typedef struct mitabla {
     std::string Nombre;
     int Tipo;
     dato Valor;
} ALIAS;        //Faltaba un alias

struct TablaArray {
    mitabla tablasimb[10];
};
```

Agrega los metodos de que desees a TablaArray.

Ahora puedes instanciar en tu codigo `struct TablaArray` y entonces estaras instanciando al arreglo que deseas. 
Entonces `main` quedaria:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    TablaArray tabla; //TablaArray: tipo dato --- tabla: nombre
    //Lo que desees hacer

}
```

Fijate que en `main` estabas tratando de crear la variable de tipo `tabla`, que no estaba definida.